# Размер фрейма не меняется

Tags: python, tkinter

По нажатию на кнопки размер фрейма должен меняться, но происходит что-то странное.

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

def size():
    if but1['text'] == 'easy':
        fra['width']='500'
        fra['height']='500'
def size1():        
    if but2['text'] == 'media':
        fra['width']='600'
        fra['height']='600'
def size2():

    if but3['text'] == 'hard':
        fra['width']='700'
        fra['height']='700 '   

fra=Frame(root,bg='lightgreen',height=550,width=550)
fra.pack()

but1=Button(fra,text="easy",command=size)
but1.pack()
but2=Button(fra,text="media",command=size1)
but2.pack()
but3=Button(fra,text="hard",command=size2)
but3.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого используйте `pack_propagate()` он включает или отключает распространении информации о геометрии дочерних виджетов. Это необходимо чтобы виджет имел фиксированный размер и не изменял его по прихоти потомков

```
from tkinter import*


def size(event):
    if event.widget["text"] == 'easy':
        fra['width'], fra['height'] = '500', "500"
    elif event.widget["text"] == 'media':
        fra['width'], fra['height'] = '600', "600"
    elif event.widget["text"] == 'hard':
        fra['width'], fra['height'] = '700', "700"


root = Tk()
fra = Frame(root, bg='lightgreen', height=550, width=550)
fra.pack()
fra.pack_propagate(False)

but1 = Button(fra, text="easy")
but1.pack()
but2 = Button(fra, text="media")
but2.pack()
but3 = Button(fra, text="hard")
but3.pack()

root.bind_class("Button", "<ButtonRelease-1>", size)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое.